# NodeJS - Apollo Server: Request disconnected during file upload stream parsing

Tags: node.js, stream, graphql

I am sending a file from the `client` to `apollo-server` which will then make another request to service with the file.

Here's an example of the code:

```
import request from "request"

uploadFile: async (_, { file } => {
  const { filename, createReadStream } = await file
  const stream = createReadStream()

  const options = {
    method: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:5000/api/upload",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    },
    formData: {
      file: {
        value: stream,
        options: {
          filename,
          contentType: null,
        },
      },
    },
  }

  request(options, err => console.log(err))
})
```

Which results in the following error:

```
BadRequestError: form-data: Request disconnected during file upload stream parsing.
    at IncomingMessage.abort (/Users/hansel/Documents/LIT/Development/creators-app/server/node_modules/graphql-upload/lib/processRequest.js:89:33)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:417:28)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)
    at resOnFinish (_http_server.js:685:7)
    at ServerResponse.emit (events.js:323:22)
    at ServerResponse.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)
    at onFinish (_http_outgoing.js:730:10)
    at onCorkedFinish (_stream_writable.js:721:5)
    at afterWrite (_stream_writable.js:528:5)
    at afterWriteTick (_stream_writable.js:515:10)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:83:21) {
  message: 'form-data: Request disconnected during file upload stream parsing.',
  expose: true,
  statusCode: 499,
  status: 499
}
```

The `file` is a valid readable stream. The error only occurs when I try to send it in a request.

If I replace the `stream` with `fs.createReadStream("filePath")` the request works fine.

Anyone ran into this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to await your async uploadFile in resolver, for example:

```
Mutation:{
uploadFile:async (_, { file }, { uploadFile}) => {
  await uploadFile(file)
}}
```